# Use Adcolony on app that isn't publish on Google Play Store

Tags: android, adcolony

Can I use Adcolony video ad if I'm not going to publish it on Google Play Store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal or licensing issues, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdColony video can only be used in apps that are published on the iTunes, Google Play or Amazon stores.